# Javascript finding text in image

Tags: javascript

I've found the following Javascript [code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/suxSx/4a55ed6e209a0c9b160589e4f232d141/raw/868f9740c107d993a8a0ce0e670a5f6a1583eff5/index.html)

I'm able to remove some of the eggs using:

```
var geometry = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    geometry.push(new Egg([16-i*10, -2, -33+i*13], 6, 1.40 + i*0.1 - (i%2)*0.2, textures[i % 5], 0.001));
}
```

and then rotate the third egg using:

```
i = 3
turn = 0.400
geometry.push(new Egg([16-i*10, -2, -33+i*13], 5, 1.60 + i*0.1 - (i%2)*0.2, textures[i % 5], turn));
```

But, how do I find where the text on the egg is located to edit the string?

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do (or how adding a new egg "removes" anything). Are you asking how to do object and text detection in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is a puzzle for you to solve, so I'll put in some spoilers.

The basic trick is that:

> The text is encoded as a bitmap in the strings `97488177650475889438078633...`, `75635063834353350663031884...` etc.

> The pattern is overlaid onto egg in a 94x5 bitmap. Each of the entry in the `Q` array corresponds to one row of the bitmap.

> The encoding is that `[012479]` corresponds to a pink pixel, and `[3568]` corresponds to a blue pixel.

> You can make a simple altered pattern using just e.g. `0` and `8`, e.g. `"08080808080808080..."`.

Fun stuff!

Comment: Great - thanks! This isn't a puzzle I have to solve - it's something I want to use for the basis of a puzzle I'm creating. But I need to update the message as it's not relevant!